# Teststack White How to Close an MDI Window

Tags: white-framework

I get a MDI window in the following way:

```
UIItemContainer myWindow = _mainwindow.MdiChild(SearchCriteria.ByControlType(ControlType.Window).AndAutomationId("65281"));
```

How do I close the window retrieved?

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the WindowPattern for the MDI child window.  If the element implements the pattern, then it should provide a method to close it:

```
var windowPattern = myWindow.GetPattern<WindowPattern>();
windowPattern.Close();
```

Comment: I get the folllowing error when I call  `var windowPattern = myWindow.GetPattern<WindowPattern>();` 'IUIItemContainer' does not contain a definition for 'GetPattern' ...

Comment: Try casting myWindow to type Window first

Comment: When I try to cast the object returned by `var scheduleWindow = _mainwindow.MdiChild(SearchCriteria.ByControlType(ControlType.Window).AndAutomationId("65281"));`   I get the exception:   _Unable to cast object of type 'TestStack.White.UIItems.UIItemContainer' to type 'TestStack.White.UIItems.WindowItems.Window_